# Changing interpolated variable value in a string after string value assignment in php

Tags: php, reference

Is it possible to change the value of a string like this. See code below:

```
$name = 'Henk';
$str = "Hi $name how are you?";

$name = 'Kees';    
echo $str; // prints: Hi Henk how are you?
```

I want to print:

```
Hi Kees how are you?
```

Comment: You're probably looking for something more akin to [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf). What you're implying code wise isn't possible as you can't bind variables (rather than values) to strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `sprintf` function.

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php (example 1)

---

Thanks for the code. I rewrote the code like this:

```
$name = 'Henk';
$format = 'Hi, %s how are you';
echo sprintf($format, $name); //Hi, Henk how are you

$name = 'Kees';
echo sprintf($format, $name); //Hi, Kees how are you
```